# How to return a reference to a new object instance from a member function (after some operation)?

Tags: c++, function, class, constants

I am trying to create a Matrix class "ECE_Matrix". It will take constant ECE_Matrix and perform all the general operations. The operations should not change the passed instance.

For the transpose, I am trying to return a reference to a new transposed Mat instance inside the member function. However, I am getting bad_alloc error. But it worked for a few times with the same code, I am confused. I am also trying to extend the same idea to addition operator overloading and chaining.

I do not want to return the this pointer, since the member functions should be const. I want to create a new instance within the member function, and return a reference to that new member as the output. I am doing this currently,

```
    const ECE_Matrix& transpose() const
{
    ECE_Matrix M(m_col, m_row, 0);

    std::vector<std::vector<double> > t_matrix( m_col, std::vector<double>(m_row, 0));

    for (int i=0; i < m_row; ++i)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < m_col; ++j)
            {
                t_matrix[j][i] = m_matrix[i][j];
            }
    }

    M.setMatrix(t_matrix);
    const ECE_Matrix* mp = &M;
    return *mp;

}
```

However, this is giving me bad_alloc error while running (the program is compiling though.)

Moreover while trying to do a similar thing with operator overloading of the + operator, I am having a similar issue:

I am trying the operator overload like:

```
const ECE_Matrix& ECE_Matrix::operator+(ECE_Matrix &M2) const
{
    ECE_Matrix M2(this->getRow(), this->getCol(), value);
    const ECE_Matrix ResultMatrix = operation(*this, M2, ADD);
    const ECE_Matrix* mp = &ResultMatrix;
    return *mp;
}
```

The overload function calls operation function to return a reference to a summed ECE_Matrix instance by the following function.

I am calculating the sum of two matrix in a function:

```
 const ECE_Matrix& operation(const ECE_Matrix &M1, const ECE_Matrix &M2, Operator opType) const

    ......CODE to calculate SUm.....

    const ECE_Matrix* mp = &M; // M is of type ECE_Matrix whose member variable holds sum.
                return *mp;
```

Even though *mp correctly points to the summed instance, after returning it, the Result_Matrix in the overloaded function is not getting the instance pointed by *mp in:

```
const ECE_Matrix ResultMatrix = operation(*this, M2, ADD);
```

What is going on? Is it something with the "this" pointer?

Comment: `return *mp;` returns a reference to a local variable that goes out of scope when the function finishes -> it becomes a dangling reference

Comment: Why do you want to return a reference? A reference to a local variable becomes dangling immediately after the function returns. You should return by value.

Comment: I want the chaining of addition operations. Such as M1+ M2 + 6.0 +M3. I tried return by value first but it didn't work. Then I just modified the instance, and returned *this. That worked but I can't modify the instance as the inputs should be constant types. Then I'm trying this out. I can't seem to find a way to make it both not change the self instance and also chain

Comment: If you take by const reference, and return by value you can still chain without any UB

Comment: @Rio1210 Returning by value should work. Can you post your failed attempt?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat 
Here is the main.cpp: https://pastebin.com/a2bvk1yN
The headerfile contain the class and members: https://pastebin.com/Ck4xmabX
All the Functions: https://pastebin.com/u4dcwPp4

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you. This is currently chaining now with return by value. I wasn't taking by const reference before, while I was trying return by value. Now it works. Thanks! But could you also explain the mechanics? Like why passing by const ref is allowing chaining, and without it, it doesn't allow? Thanks

Comment: @rio1210 the reason it works is because taking by const reference allows you to capture temporaries, wick is what you have when returning by value.  A non const reference can't bind to temporaries so that's why you had to return by reference in your original code.

Answer (score 1):

The line below

```
  return *mp;
```

Creates a Dangling pointer at the end of the code snippet in the post, as pointed out by the first two comments to the post. I finally solved the issue with return by value, while taking a const ref as input as pointed out by @NathanOliver.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could create a new instance of your ECE_Matrix class inside your method, like this:

```
ECE_Matrix M = new ECE_Matrix(m_col, m_row, 0);
```

The problem is you transfer ownership of that pointer to the calling function, which can get confusing and often (especially in bigger projects) leads to memory leaks.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how this works? How will I be returning my calculation to the calling function via this method? Thanks.

Comment: It would create a new instance of the ECE_Matrix class on the heap (instead of a variable on the stack, which goes out scope when the function completes). You'd return a pointer to this new instance of ECE_Matrix.  The instance of ECE_Matrix would exist until you deleted it or the application exits.